# Makefile - Efficient Compiling

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

Let's say, compiling hello.c requires car.c and water.c.
But main.c requires hello.c.

When I say requires, I mean that the compiled output would differ if the things it requires is modified in any way.

So, if car.c or water.c is changed, then hello.c would need recompiling.

Then, would this be the correct Makefile?

```
main: main hello.o

  gcc main.c hello.c -o main

hello.o: water.c, car.c

  gcc water.c car.c -o hello.o
```

Otherwise, if it's not correct, can someone explain to me why it is wrong and give me an example?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not  a code review site. Do you have any specific problem with that makefile? Otherwise, I propose just to test it and dump the rules for instance.

Comment: A) `main` should not depend on itself. B) there are plenty of make tutorials out there.

Comment: Having any .c file depend on another .c file is bizarre at best.

Comment: The problem you have described doesn't really make much sense. Source files do not depend on other source files. Object files depend on source files and executable files depend on object files (or, arguably source files).

Comment: without associated header files, these .c files will not be able to talk to each other as any one .c file would not know the prototypes for the functions in the other files.    I.E. there needs to be main.h, car.h, water.c, hello.h .   The compile statements need to know where to find the header files (#include "..." statements in the .c files)  so the compile statements need a '-I.'  or similar parameter and the appropriate header files need to be listed in the 'target: dependency list' for each compile rule.

Comment: You really don't want the comma in the line `hello.o: water.c, car.c`. That looks for a file with a `.c,` extension; the comma is part of the file name as far as `make` is concerned.

Comment: If the .c files are written correctly, all they will expose to the other .c files is an interface (the function prototypes and type definitions)  So the other .c files will only need to be modified if that interface is changed.  The evidence of a change would be in the associated .h file(s)

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say, compiling hello.c requires car.c and water.c. But main.c requires hello.c.

This statement doesn't make a lot of sense.  The only thing it could mean is that either these aren't C or C++ source files, rather some other language that uses these names confusingly, or they contain `#include` directives that include those other files.

In that latter case (which is rare, and a poor design), there's no need to specify the included files on the command line, since gcc will include them for you.  You just need to specify the dependencies in the Makefile:

```
main: main.c hello.c car.c water.c
        gcc -o main main.c
```

since `main.c` has `#include "hello.c"` and `hello.c` has `#include "car.c"` and `#include "water.c"`, only the one compile gets everything.

If these are some other language, and you mean something completely different, its likely that `gcc` can't understand (or compile) them at all...

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is a little strange, but I guess not incorrect. Don't have a recursive dependency on main and compile hello.o as an object file.

> ```
> main: main.c hello.o
>     gcc main.c hello.o -o main
>
> hello.o: hello.c water.c car.c
>     gcc hello.c water.c car.c -c hello.o
> ```

Comment: The last line is nonsensical -- it triggers an error from gcc: `gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files`

Answer (score 0):

In your makefile there are entities of the following type:

- final executable program: `main`
- compiled objects (relocatable ELFs linked into the `main` executable). I can see `hello.o`, *but* I cannot find `water.o`, `car.o` and `main.o` (since each `*.c` compilation unit is generally converted by the compiler to a `*.o` compiled object).
- the source files (compilations units): `main.c`, `hello.c`, `water.c` and `car.c`. These are used as inputs by the compiler to generate the corresponding `*.o` files.

So, based on the above, the appropriate Makefile would look like this (*tested*):

```
main.o:
        gcc -c main.c

hello.o:
        gcc -c hello.c

water.o:
        gcc -c water.c

car.o:
        gcc -c car.c

main: hello.o water.o car.o main.o
        gcc hello.o water.o car.o main.o -o main
```

The shortened versioned, using makefile [text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) (*tested*):

```
%.o:
        gcc -c $(addsuffix .c, $(basename $@))

main: hello.o water.o car.o main.o
        gcc $^ -o main
```

Another approach (*tested*):

```
SRC := hello.c water.c car.c main.c
OBJ := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRC)))

main: $(OBJ)
        gcc $^ -o main
```

Comment: `make` knows how to compile `.o` files from `.c` files without you needing to write a `%.o` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write it as:

```
SRC := hello.c main.c water.c
OBJS := $(patsubt %.c,%.o,$(SRC))

main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

This makefile works because there is an implicit rule for compiling C files. This will mean that when $(OBJS) is expanded to hello.o, main.o, and water.o, each of those .o files will be built by "$(CC) -o hello.o -c hello.c".

Note that if you use the GCC -c flag to only compile the file, but not link it, you will not need to be worried that hello.c relies on car.c and water.c.

EDIT:

Note that in your original makefile, the line "main: main hello.o" is incorrect. A target cannot depend on itself.

In general, with Make, you want to specify dependencies, but not the implementation of making those dependencies, if you can help it. It is much cleaner to say "I need this" versus "do these steps". In a lot of cases, Make is smart enough that if you say "I need this," it will "do the right thing."